# Recommendations for particular brand/models of shower enclosures?

Tags: bathroom, shower

We have a partially finished basement. Our unfinished laundry had a toilet and sink in the corner. Both are ancient and we're going to replace them. Still, they're in the corner of our laundry room, so I was going to build some form of half/wall stall, fix the floor and...

...well then I realized I maybe should just go all-in and actually make it a proper enclosed bath. The question now is do we keep it a half bath or go for a 3/4 by adding a shower. It's in the basement, but given the location of the current main drain, it looks like I could easily add a shower on an 8" platform and still have plenty of slope for a proper drain without having to tear up the concrete.

Shower surrounds seem to come in 100 different models and manufacturers. Many are cheaply made. The question I have is: in general, are there particular brands/models/types I should avoid and or focus on? I'm looking for relatively small (probably 3' x 3' at the largest). A multi-piece would probably be a necessity given that this has to get into our basement.

Comment: I can't say I have enough experience with different shower enclosures to speak with authority. However, I've noticed that an inordinate number of Lasco shower enclosures installed in many apartments and homes throughout my local area (I've been looking for a place lately and randomly started noticing Lasco showers a lot). They always seem pleasant, nothing that fancy. I went to look them up just now and it seems they've merged with another company called Aquatic. There website is here: http://www.aquaticbath.com/ Just my $0.02, hopefully someone has more experience and can help more.